# ASP.Net view folder with a folder inside - How to create the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a URL similar to: localhost:port/farm/animals/cow.cshtml.
How do I create a controller for pages behind /animals/ ?

If I create a standard:

```
public class FarmController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Farm/

    public ActionResult Cow()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I will not get there because the cow.cshtml is behind the animals.
Nor will I get to cow.cshtml with the following code:

```
public class AnimalsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Animals/

    public ActionResult Cow()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Because the link to cow.cshtml is not /animals/ but /farm/animals/cow.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does it have to be MVC4? Can you use MVC5?

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue, [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) might help.

Comment: Sorry, the tag does imply I use MVC4 but yes I use MVC5 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register a route like the following -

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Animals",
            url: "farm/animals/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Farm" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class FarmController : Controller
{
    // GET: Farm
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Farm/Animals
    public ActionResult Animals()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Farm/Animals/Cow
    public ActionResult Cow()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would I then use the Farmcontroller to get to cow.cshtml, or use the animalscontroller?

Comment: Having both FarmController and Animal Controller does make sense. You just need to user **FarmController**. I updated the answer.

Comment: I've done exactly that. However when I try to go to /farm/animals/cow I actually get send to the animals.cshtml in /farm/.

Comment: Did you register the route?

Comment: Yes, I have registered the route and done the controller part. Perhaps it goes wrong with the link on the website that should go to the cow.cshtml: <li><a href="../farm/animals/Cow">Cow</a></li>

Comment: I tested the above code and it works fine. You need to create a new MVC project and test it.

Comment: I've done that, when going to ...website:port/farm/animals/cow I actually get send to website:port/farm/cow where it tries to find a cow.cshtml file which is not there. To make sure you understand the folder tree: Views/Farm/Animals/Cow.cshtml is the entire path in my VS. The error I get when going to /farm/animals/cow is: The view 'Cow' or its master was not found in the ~/Views/Farm/Cow.cshtml directory.

Comment: Cow.cshtml should be located next to Animals.cshtml and Index.cshtml. Look at the screenshot that I updated. MVC View Folder should not be nested like traditional ASP.Net WebForm; it is the beauty of MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst routing would solve your problem, this sounds like a job for [MVC areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If in your actual application you're wanting to separate parts of your site, then an area might be the solution here.